# Remove undefined elements from array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects, some of these objects have the property "discount" with a value and some of them don't have the property at all. When I loop thru the array I would like to remove all the undefined elements because this is giving me an error. Here's some images to show you my issue:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

```js
var data = [
  {
    product: "Dusty Jumpsuit",
    url: "",
    image: "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/560c458be4b0af26f729d191/560c5de0e4b083d9c365515f/560d4d0de4b0edc898c43a14/1443712276073/kimem-dusty-jumpsuit_0358.jpg?format=2500w",
    altDesc: "Blouse",
    price: "$299.00",
    discount: "$350.00"
  },
  {
    product: "Jacky Trousers",
    url: "",
    image: "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/560c458be4b0af26f729d191/560c5de0e4b083d9c365515f/560d4d2fe4b0edc898c43b3c/1443712308758/kimem-jacky-bicolor-waist-trousers-navy-black_0374+%28Michelle+Liv%27s+conflicted+copy+2015-08-31%29.jpg?format=750w",
    altDesc: "Pants",
    price: "$228.00"
  },
  {
    product: "Lisa Shirt",
    url: "",
    image: "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/560c458be4b0af26f729d191/560c5de0e4b083d9c365515f/560d4d67e4b094d8b81ba47a/1443712364244/kimem-lisa-oversized-shirt-navy_0363.jpg?format=750w",
    altDesc: "Shirt",
    price: "$253.00"
  },
  {
    product: "Jane Skirt",
    url: "",
    image: "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/560c458be4b0af26f729d191/560c5de0e4b083d9c365515f/560d4d8fe4b0f1182e35da9a/1443712404868/kimem-long-pleated-skirt-black_0354.jpg?format=750w",
    altDesc: "Shirt",
    price: "$150.00",
    discount: "$263.00"
  },
];

function clothingView(item, index) {
  return (`
    <a href="${item.url}" class="shop-item">
      <img src=${item.image} alt="${item.altDesc}" class="shop-item__img">
      <div class="quickview">
        <span class="quickview__icon">Quick View</span>
        <span class="quickview__info">${item.product}
          <br>
          <span class="quickview__price">${item.price}<span class="quickview__price--discount">${item.discount}<span></span>
        </span>
        <span class="clothing-index">${index}</span>
      </div>
    </a>`)
};

var $productContainer = $('.products');
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  $productContainer.append( clothingView(data[i], i) )
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 40%;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}

body {
  font-family: "Karla", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.6;
  color: #222;
}

.products {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.shop-item {
  width: calc(100% / 5);
  margin: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.shop-item__img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.quickview {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  color: #222;
  letter-spacing: 0.15rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

.quickview:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.quickview__icon {
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.9);
  padding: 0.7rem 1rem;
  align-self: center;
}

.quickview__info {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  align-self: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.quickview__info--price {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.6);
}

.clothing-index {
  display: none;
}

.quickview__price--discount {
  margin-left: .5rem;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="products all-items"></div>
```

I need to learn how to explain myself better, but I hope the images and the sample code is good enough to clarify the situation here. I tried adding {discount: ""} to all objects but I am not sure if that would be the best way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the template literal so that if there is no `discount` property, the `quickview__price--discount` `span` is not included in the HTML string:

```
function clothingView(item, index) {
  return (`
    <a href="${item.url}" class="shop-item">
      <img src=${item.image} alt="${item.altDesc}" class="shop-item__img">
      <div class="quickview">
        <span class="quickview__icon">Quick View</span>
        <span class="quickview__info">${item.product}
          <br>
          <span class="quickview__price">${item.price}
          ${ item.discount
             ? `<span class="quickview__price--discount">${item.discount}<span>`
             : '' }
          </span>
        </span>
        <span class="clothing-index">${index}</span>
      </div>
    </a>`)
};
```

```js
var data = [
  {
    product: "Dusty Jumpsuit",
    url: "",
    image: "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/560c458be4b0af26f729d191/560c5de0e4b083d9c365515f/560d4d0de4b0edc898c43a14/1443712276073/kimem-dusty-jumpsuit_0358.jpg?format=2500w",
    altDesc: "Blouse",
    price: "$299.00",
    discount: "$350.00"
  },
  {
    product: "Jacky Trousers",
    url: "",
    image: "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/560c458be4b0af26f729d191/560c5de0e4b083d9c365515f/560d4d2fe4b0edc898c43b3c/1443712308758/kimem-jacky-bicolor-waist-trousers-navy-black_0374+%28Michelle+Liv%27s+conflicted+copy+2015-08-31%29.jpg?format=750w",
    altDesc: "Pants",
    price: "$228.00"
  },
  {
    product: "Lisa Shirt",
    url: "",
    image: "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/560c458be4b0af26f729d191/560c5de0e4b083d9c365515f/560d4d67e4b094d8b81ba47a/1443712364244/kimem-lisa-oversized-shirt-navy_0363.jpg?format=750w",
    altDesc: "Shirt",
    price: "$253.00"
  },
  {
    product: "Jane Skirt",
    url: "",
    image: "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/560c458be4b0af26f729d191/560c5de0e4b083d9c365515f/560d4d8fe4b0f1182e35da9a/1443712404868/kimem-long-pleated-skirt-black_0354.jpg?format=750w",
    altDesc: "Shirt",
    price: "$150.00",
    discount: "$263.00"
  },
];

function clothingView(item, index) {
  return (`
    <a href="${item.url}" class="shop-item">
      <img src=${item.image} alt="${item.altDesc}" class="shop-item__img">
      <div class="quickview">
        <span class="quickview__icon">Quick View</span>
        <span class="quickview__info">${item.product}
          <br>
          <span class="quickview__price">${item.price}
          ${ item.discount
             ? `<span class="quickview__price--discount">${item.discount}<span>`
             : '' }
          </span>
        </span>
        <span class="clothing-index">${index}</span>
      </div>
    </a>`)
};

var $productContainer = $('.products');
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  $productContainer.append( clothingView(data[i], i) )
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 40%;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}

body {
  font-family: "Karla", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.6;
  color: #222;
}

.products {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container {
  padding: 4rem 5rem !important;
}

.shop-item {
  width: calc(100% / 4);
  margin: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.shop-item__img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.quickview {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  color: #222;
  letter-spacing: 0.15rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

.quickview:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.quickview__icon {
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.9);
  padding: 0.7rem 1rem;
  align-self: center;
}

.quickview__info {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  align-self: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.quickview__info--price {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.6);
}

.popup {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(245, 239, 236, 0.8);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

.popup__img {
  height: 95%;
}

.popup__close-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  right: 2.5rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: #d1d1d1;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

.popup__close-icon:hover {
  color: rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.6);
}

.popup__close-icon-clothing {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 3.6rem;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: #222;
  top: -1rem;
  right: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overscroll-behavior: contain;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.6);
}

.popup-item {
  width: 75%;
  height: 150vh;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 5rem auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.product-info {
  padding: 5rem 3.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  color: #222;
}

.product-info--shop {
  padding: 0 3.5rem;
}

.product__price {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  margin: 3rem 0;
  display: block;
  color: rgba(29, 29, 29, 0.7);
}

.product-info__text {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  color: rgba(29, 29, 29, 0.7);
}

.detail-group {
  color: #222;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

.detail-group__span {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.detail-group__size {
  width: 12.5rem;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  padding: 1.1rem 2rem;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  background: url(../img/down-arrow.png) 85%/7% no-repeat #f8f8f8;
}

.detail-group__quantity {
  width: 7.5rem;
  padding: 1.1rem 1.6rem;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.clothing-item-flex {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
}

.clothing-item-flex__img-wrapper {
  min-width: 60%;
  margin: 1.5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.clothing-item-flex__img-wrapper--no-margin {
  margin: 0;
}

.clothing-item-flex__img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  padding: 1.2rem 2.6rem;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}
.btn:hover {
  color: #222;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.btn--form {
  color: #222;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 1.4rem 3.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn--form:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #222;
}
.btn--form--shop {
  padding: 2.3rem 3.4rem;
}

.btn-view {
  display: block;
  width: 10.5rem;
  margin-top: 4rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.6);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(162, 162, 162, 0.7);
}

.popup-btn {
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 9%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.popup-btn--prev {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  left: 9%;
}
.popup-btn__icon {
  height: 100%;
}

.clothing-index {
  display: none;
}

.quickview__price--discount {
  margin-left: .5rem;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="products all-items"></div>
```

Comment: But your code is removing the "clothing items" altogether, I just want to remove the undefined from the objects that dont have the discount property so when I hover I don't see undefined on my items.

Comment: See edit, you'll have to change the template literal - if the object has the `discount` property, include the `quickview__price--discount` span, otherwise don't include it

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect, exactly what was looking for. BTW can you provide me with the code from your original answer, I think it's gonna be useful to me for another functionality of this app. Later on I want to divide these objects in sections (bottoms, accesories, etc).

Comment: You can click on the "edited" element to see past revisions

Comment: Oh that's great, thank you very much for your help, appreciate it!